# Calculate Wind Chill

Tags: code-golf, math

The Australian Apparent Temperature (aka, wind chill) in °C `AT` is given by this algorithm from the Australian Bureau of Meterology ([wp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill#Australian_Apparent_Temperature), [source](http://www.bom.gov.au/info/thermal_stress/#atapproximation)):

[image]

```
AT = Ta + (0.33 * e) - (.7 * ws) - 4.0
```

Where:

> `Ta` = Dry bulb temperature (°C)
>
> `e` = Water vapour pressure (hPa)
>
> `ws` = Wind speed (m/s) (at an elevation of 10 meters)

The water vapour pressure in hectoPascals `e` is given by this algorithm:

[image]

```
e = (rh / 100) * 6.105 * exp( ( 17.27 * Ta ) / ( 237.7 + Ta ) )
```

Where:

> `Ta` = Dry bulb temperature (°C)
>
> `rh` = Relative humidity [%]
>
> `exp`  represents the exponential function

The domain of:

> - `Ta` is -273.15°C to 2e7°C.
> - `e` is the real numbers
> - `ws` is 0 m/s to 2e7 m/s
> - `rh` is 0% to 100%

For inputs outside these domains, your code can do anything, including give the right answer.

---

### Output

Given a dry bulb **temperature** in °C, a **wind speed** in metres / second, and a **relative humidity** in %, your code should give the Apparent Temperature in °C, accurate to 0.1°C.

Assuming your platform or language can represent reals, for correct functions `correct_func`,

[image]

or in C, `fabsl( correct_func(Ta, rH, ws) - expected ) < 0.1`.

#### Test cases

```
1 value for Ta, rh, ws -> output

0 -> -4
2 -> -3.35346
4 -> -2.69275
6 -> -2.01507
8 -> -1.31719
10 -> -0.595428
12 -> 0.154404
14 -> 0.937065
16 -> 1.75793
18 -> 2.62308
20 -> 3.5393
22 -> 4.51423
24 -> 5.55638
26 -> 6.67525
28 -> 7.88137
30 -> 9.18643

49, 99, 67 -> 36.268
```

Repl.it for any test case: https://repl.it/H9xL/0

You can use a builtin function for the exponential function,
`ex`, if you like.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: Is there a single input to the program or are the test cases just weird?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The algorithm takes three inputs, but I was lazy in creating the test cases, using one value for three args.

Comment: This challenge doesn't really have much room for golfing.

Comment: Without any bound on the inputs, a finite precision on `e` makes it impossible to be within 0.1 degree on all onputs. Or is this only on the test cases?

Comment: @xnor The inputs *have* bounds. "For inputs outside these domains, your code can do anything, including give the right answer."

Comment: @xnor the point of that was to say that results should be accurate to the .1s (tenths) place and that following, more precise digits do not matter. did i say it in an unclear way?

Comment: This isn't a problem with the people. There's little room for creativity when the algorithm is straight-up the simplest way to solve it.

Comment: My mistake. So I guess golfers would need to figure out how much precision is needed in each constant by looking at how much inaccuracy the rounding causes on extremal cases.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
t=lambda T,r,V:.0201465*r*2.718281828459045**(1727*T/(100*T+23770))+T-.7*V-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#YlFOZ)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>78</s> <s>72</s> 66 bytes

Pretty much a direct implementation of the algorithm provided in the challenge description.

```python
lambda T,r,w:T+.0201465*r*2.7182818284**(17.27*T/(237.7+T))-.7*w-4
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcPBCsIwDADQs35Fjm2W1TarZgz8ix69VLRSmFWCsM@vyuOV86Wv@Xm9ZUiktC1pcJ59iKcjKrKTMPP8HxFNEMeC6WB4EidDsnZ0gtsYe3kpVKgNNLfH3XiaArFd9ru31vaBYir92P4F)

This was specifically tested with the maximum value of `T` to find how many digits of Euler's constant were required for the error to be within the allowed amount.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, 41 bytes

```
:Prompt T,R,W
:T-.7W-4+.02014565Re^(17.27T/(237.7+T
```

Surprisingly, a calculator is really good at crunching numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 56 bytes

```js
(a,r,w)=>a+.0201465*r*Math.exp(17.27*a/(237.7+a))-.7*w-4
```

```js
var f = (a,r,w)=>a+.0201465*r*Math.exp(17.27*a/(237.7+a))-.7*w-4
var expected = [-4, -3.35346, -2.69275, -2.01507, -1.31719, -0.595428, 0.154404, 0.937065, 1.75793, 2.62308, 3.5393, 4.51423, 5.55638, 6.67525, 7.88137, 9.18643]; for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {var g = f(2*i,2*i,2*i); var diff = expected[i] - g; document.getElementById('w').innerHTML += '\n' + ((diff > 0.1 || diff < -0.1) ? 'KO' : 'OK') + '   ' + (expected[i] - g) + '   ' + g + '   ' + expected[i];}
```

```html
<pre id="w">Passed  |  Diff  |  Actual result  |  Expected</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>54</s> 49 bytes

```python
@(T,r,V).0201465*r*e^(17.27*T/(237.7+T))+T-.7*V-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#bFZmq)

Comment: `(17.27*T/(237.7+T)` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
U+.0#É465*V*MEp17.27*U/(#í.7 +U)-.7*W-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@qrWegfLjTxMxUK0zL17XA0FzPyFwrVF9D@fBaPXMF7VBNXT1zrXBdk///zXUUQAgA)

This is my first Japt answer, so please don't judge it too harshly ;-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for using Japt :-) You can save a couple bytes by replacing `201` and `237` with `#É` and `#í`, respectively. (It's an odd trick, but it works...)

Comment: @ETHproductions: that's odd indeed. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 52 (possibly non-competing)

```
{$^a+.0201465*$^c*exp(17.27*$a/(237.7+$a))-4-.7*$^b}
```

This can't be evaluated by itself. You either have to pass in arguments, or store the block into a variable.

Comment: What do you mean, “This can't be evaluated by itself”? As I see, it can be called as any anonymous function. (Maybe you should specify that it expects parameters in Ta, ws, rh order.)

Comment: If you type it by itself in the REPL, you'll get an error. You either have to pass in the arguments, or assign the block to a variable.

Comment: Sure you have to pass it arguments, but no need to assign to variable. https://pastebin.com/7W3cJSrX This is the same as calling anonymous functions in other languages.

Comment: What I meant was that if you typed the expression alone without either, you got an error.